# In MySQL, list friend requests from and to users liking the same post

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
users(id_user, name, ...)
post(id, id_user, status, ...)
likes(id, id_post, id_user)
friendship(id, id_friend_one, id_friend_two)
request(id, id_friend_one, id_friend_two, status)
```

The meaning of `request.status` is

- sent for 0,
- pending for 1 and
- friends for 2.

I want to see users who have clicked “like” on the post and whether a user has sent me a friend request or if I sent a request.

If I click

> [image: like button]

I want to get

> [image: list of sent and received friend requests by people liking that post]

I use this query:

```
SELECT
    u.id_users,
    u.name,
    u.pic_profile_small,
    r.id_friend_one,
    r.id_friend_two,
    r.status
FROM
    likes l
    INNER JOIN users u ON l.id_post = 12 AND u.id_users = l.id_user
    LEFT JOIN request r ON id_friend_one = l.id_user
```

The problem is that if a user has more than 2 friend requests, the resulting user information appears repeated many times.

Comment: Will you please create an [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for this?

Comment: The `l.id_post = 12` should rather be in a `WHERE` clause, because it has nothing to do with joining, you’re just filtering the results by this condition.

Comment: You use `u.id_users` instead of `u.id_user`. This should not work. Probably you just made an error when writing the question. From your database schema I assume the latter is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You’re getting duplicate results because you did not specify which user you are and that you are not interested in status 2. But there are many more problems with your schema and query.

You do not mention the meaning of columns in the `request` table. Who sent the request and who received it? It looks like that is indicated by the `status` column. If `status = 0`, `id_friend_one` sent the request; if `status = 1`, `id_friend_two` sent the request; if `status = 2`, we don’t know (nor care). This is a bad design. Either of these two requests would have the same meaning; would you insert them both?

```
INSERT INTO request(id_friend_one, id_friend_two, status) VALUES (1, 2, 0);
INSERT INTO request(id_friend_one, id_friend_two, status) VALUES (2, 1, 1);
```

Therefore I’ll rename `id_friend_one` to `id_from` and `id_friend_two` to `id_to`. Now `id_from` is the user who sends the request.

Now what’s the meaning of `status`. Original status 0 and 1 is now the same. I’ll add one status of the request that you did not mention, and that is “rejected”. So now `status` is

- 0 for sent,
- 1 for accepted and
- 2 for rejected.

I’ll assume, that your app takes care to ensure that in any moment, for each pair of users, there is at most one request with status 0 in any direction. Otherwise, you’ll get duplicate results.

```
SELECT
    u.id_user,
    u.name,
    u.pic_profile_small,
    0 AS direction -- sent
FROM
    likes l
    JOIN request r ON r.id_to = l.id_user
    JOIN users u ON u.id_user = l.id_user
WHERE
    l.id_post = 12 AND
    r.id_from = 42 AND
    r.status = 0
UNION
SELECT
    u.id_user,
    u.name,
    u.pic_profile_small,
    1 AS direction -- received
FROM
    likes l
    JOIN request r ON r.id_from = l.id_user
    JOIN users u ON u.id_user = l.id_user
WHERE
    l.id_post = 12 AND
    r.id_to = 42 AND
    r.status = 0
```

This can be rewritten to be less repetitive using a subquery (or a view), which will essentially dynamically create your original table, but it will be sure to be consistent and contain records for both directions. I’m not sure if that is a good practice and which of the two approaches is better/faster, or if they produce the same schedule. Union is making two queries and mixing the results together, which seems natural to me in this case. Adding the second approach for the sake of completeness.

```
SELECT
    u.id_user,
    u.name,
    u.pic_profile_small,
    r.direction -- 0 = sent, 1 = received
FROM
    likes l
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            id_from AS id_user,
            id_to AS id_other,
            status,
            0 AS direction -- sent
        FROM
            request
        UNION
        SELECT
            id_to AS id_user,
            id_from AS id_other,
            status,
            1 AS direction -- received
        FROM
            request
    ) r ON r.id_other = l.id_user
    JOIN users u ON u.id_user = l.id_user
WHERE
    l.id_post = 12 AND
    r.id_user = 42 AND
    r.status = 0
```

Comment: sorry for late answer, is that I travel, I'll consider your advice. thank you very much.